# Need to get info from any element, which was clicked, but not from parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to get info from any element, which was clicked.

Example:

```
<div>text1<section>text2</section></div>
```

and JS

```
$(function(){
  $('body *').click(function(){
    alert($(this).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

If I click text2, parent element throw alert too. I need only first alert from section. How I can block next alerts from all parent elements of section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from firing on the containing elements.

```
$(function(){
  $('body *').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to expand on Kooilnc answer - Using `on` with `event delegation` is another option.

Event delegation would be nice if you have an event listener bound before or after on a node that needs to listen to a click handler that has bubbled up. If you `stopPropagation`, this obviously would be an issue.

Here's a fiddle with a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahgtLjbn/

Let's say a buddy of yours has bound an event listener to a node higher up in the DOM tree. He expects any events that bubble up to it, to be handled by his script.

Using `event delegation`, the event still bubbles up (so your buddies code will still fire), but it will only alert once (since we called `e.stopPropagation`).

Calling `on` without `event delegation`, or binding the event directly using `click` (which, under the hood, is just calling `on`) will prevent the event from bubbling, so your buddies code will never run.